# Baccharis neglecta vs Juniperus ashei in central texas

Tags: plants, texas

It's my understanding both [Baccharis neglecta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baccharis_neglecta) and [Juniperus ashei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juniperus_ashei) thrive in nutrient poor soils but I rarely see them together. I mean, they're both in central Texas, but like where I see Baccharis neglecta is usually dry riverbeds whereas Juniperus ashei is everywhere else.

Is there something about dry riverbeds that makes that earth inhospitable to Juniperus ashei? Is there something about overgrazed fields full of caliche that makes that earth inhospitable to Baccharis neglecta? Or in the environments where Juniperus ashei thrives does that plant just outcompete Baccharis neglecta?

Comment: Presumably the rivers are seasonal. Perhaps *Baccharis neglecta* is tolerant of (or even needs) sometimes waterlogged roots, and *Juniperus ashei* isn't/doesn't.